# RewriteRule - matching exact URLs with and without querystrings

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a list of old URLs that are being mapped to their equivalent new URL. Some of the old URLs include querystrings some do not.

There's no set pattern to the mapping, so I can't use any wildcard rules, I need to make exact matches.

I've been trying this approach:

```
RewriteRule ^products/index\.cfm\?pageName=Products/Index$ /test1/ [R=301,QSD,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^products/index\.cfm$ /test2/ [R=301,QSD,L,NC]
```

However, if I go to http://example.com/products/index.cfm?pageName=Products/Index it's getting matched in the second rule, and redirected to http://example.com/test2/

Thanks,

JT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't match against the query string in a rewrite rule's pattern. You need to match against the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pageName=Products/Index$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^products/index\.cfm$ /test1/ [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^products/index\.cfm$ /test2/ [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks Jon - works perfectly.

And for anyone using this solutions, adding the QSD flag will stop the querystring being appended to the end of the new URL.